# Error al aejecutar la actualizacion automatica

Tags: sql, powerbi

Tengo el siguiente problema:

En Power BI Report Server no actualiza el reporte cosa que en Power BI Desktop si actualiza sin problemas.

Las credenciales estan correctamente.

Evio el error que arroja:

```
SessionID: 1a183353-0d98-4750-8fff-552b29341151
[0] -1055784932: Credentials are required to connect to the SQL source. (Source at gdjnt422\sqlff4;P_REPF5.). The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[1] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[2] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[3] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[4] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[5] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[6] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[7] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[8] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[9] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[10] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[11] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[12] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[13] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[14] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
[15] -1055784932: The command has been canceled.. The exception was raised by the IDbCommand interface.
```

En el origen de datos si se conecta correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco mucho si me ayudan.

Comment: Creia que era un bug aolucionado. Si en el PBIX tienes dos datasources con el mismo nombre, asegúrate que los dos están escritos de igual forma: Por ejemplo, lo siguiente trae problemas (mayúsculas, minúsculas): server1; database1, server1; Database1

Comment: @RogerTorné Gracias por tu comentario. Pero lo solucione con una relaciones que habia en el reporte, dichas relaciones no las soporta el nuevo Power BI Desktop.